# How sum up a value from a list?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list of values which lookslike:

```
filtered_df['title_sentiment'].head()
2      {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound...
3      {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.85, 'pos': 0.15, 'compou...
12     {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.744, 'pos': 0.256, 'comp...
67     {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound...
130    {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound...
Name: title_sentiment, dtype: object
```

and I want to sum all particular values from the list such as 'pos'.

I've tried:

```
filtered_df['pos_sum'] = filtered_df['title_sentiment'].apply(lambda x: x['pos'].sum())
```

...which raises:

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'sum'

Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think `filtered_df['title_sentiment']['pos'].sum()` is what you're looking for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sum the series returned from `apply`. Try this:

```py
filtered_df['pos_sum'] = filtered_df['title_sentiment'].apply(lambda x: x['pos']).sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `x['pos']` gives you a `float`, because you are accessing the value for the corresponding 'pos' key in the dictionary. Try:

```
filtered_df['pos_sum'] = filtered_df['title_sentiment'].apply(lambda x: x['pos']).sum()
```

Extract `x['pos']` and then sum.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to extract the number from that dictionary

```
filtered_df['pos_sum'] = filtered_df['title_sentiment'].apply(lambda x: x['pos']).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
filtered_df['pos_sum'] = sum([el['pos] for el in filtered_df['title_sentiment']])
```